# how to capture 'mount' output

Tags: linux, error-handling

I think I am missing something terribly stupid, please correct me.

```
root@fdas:~# mount /dev/sdd1 /b 2>&1 > /tmp/test

mount: you must specify the filesystem type
root@fdas:~# cat /tmp/test 
root@fdas:~# mount /dev/sdd1 /b > test
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
root@fdas:~# cat test 
root@fdas:~#
```

I simply need to capture that one line of output...Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that in standard shell (not bash/csh) you need to tell it where to redirect `stdout` first and redirect `stderr` then, so you just need to swap your redirects:

```
mount /dev/sdd1 /b > /tmp/test 2>&1
```

In CSH you can use `&` as Shiplu suggested:

```
mount /dev/sdd1 /b >&  /tmp/test
```

In BASH `&` syntax is different:

```
mount /dev/sdd1 /b &>  /tmp/test
```

BASH supports CSH `&` syntax too, but it is NOT recommended (in man)

Comment: 2>&1 sends stderr(2) to what is **currently** stdout(1), so you need to do it **after** you have redirected stdout with >

Comment: Could you explain that first line of code a bit more? I understand that `> /tmp/test` direct's mount's output to a file called test, but what exactly do the symbols `2>&1` mean, individually and together?

Comment: @BoThompson 2 refers to stderr, 1 refers to stdout, good article at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)

Answer (score 1):

You want to capture `stderr`. The following will capture all.

```
mount /dev/sdd1 /b >&  /tmp/test
```

Comment: @Shiplu `&` is bash only if I'm not mistaken. And what's wrong with `2>&1 > /tmp/test`? It is supposed to work but it doesn't with some apps (including mount)

Comment: @Shiplu and why `>& /tmp/test` and not `&>/tmp/test`? they both seem to work

Comment: @0leg "what's wrong with 2>&1...it is supposed to work but it doesnt with some apps" - Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

Redirection syntax depends on the shell.
There are two types - bash (or the Bourne shell family) and csh (or the C shell family)
In csh, use "cmd >& file" to redirect both stdout & stderr.
In bash, use "cnd 2>&1 > file" to do the same.
More info [here](http://www.mathinfo.u-picardie.fr/asch/f/MeCS/courseware/users/help/general/unix/redirection.html)